connected to a broadcast channel, can send but no longer receiving. How to detect an issue and reconnect
I have a vanilla Javascript app using Supabase a broadcast channel to keep things in sync.
const client = supabase.createClient(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_KEY);
const channel = client.channel('test-channel', {});
channel
    .on(
        'broadcast',
        { event: 'timer_update' },
        (payload) => messageReceived(payload)
    )
    .subscribe((status, err) => {
        switch (status) {
        case 'SUBSCRIBED':
            $("#msg").html('Connected!');
            break;
        case 'CHANNEL_ERROR':
            console.log(err)
            $("#msg").html(`There was an error subscribing to channel: ${err.message}`)
            break;
        case 'TIMED_OUT':
            console.log(err)
            $("#msg").html('Realtime server did not respond in time.')
            break;
        case 'CLOSED':
            console.log(err)
            $("#msg").html('Realtime channel was unexpectedly closed.')
            break;
        }
    })

Sometimes (can be following a browser window sleeping or other understandable breaks in connection) my subscribe listener receives a status of CHANNEL_ERROR and no message. After that point I can still broadcast to the channel, but no longer receive messages.
I have tried doing a channel = client.removeChannel('test-channel'); so I could re-create the subscription, but that gives an error:
supabase-js@2:7 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.unsubscribe is not a function
    at x.removeChannel (supabase-js@2:7:80446)
    at t.default.removeChannel (supabase-js@2:7:97012)

I guess what I'd like to do is in the event of the error, or after a check when the window regains focus, I have a way to elegantly reconnect to listen again.
